# Post Method leads to reload instead it is a void method

Tags: spring-mvc, post

I have a Post Method which looks like

```
public void circleUpPost(HttpServletRequest _request, Model _model, @ModelAttribute("circleUpModel") CircleUpModel _circleUpModel) {

    ...
```

Within this POST Method I´m processing some stuff. When the Post method is finished the page reloads. But instead nothing should happen.

I already tried to add @ReponseBody or  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) but that doesn´t work!

Are there any suggestions?

EDIT

Maybe the submit button on my page causes the problem? But of course I have to submit my data from the view to the Post Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after I found out it really was because the submit button leads to reloading the page I replaced the submit function.

Instead I used Ajax to send the data to my Post Method !

```
    function sendData(){
    var myform = document.getElementById("circle_form");
    var form = new FormData(myform );
    $.ajax({
        url: "CircleUp",
        data: form,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Sorry for this "unnecssary" post! Hopefully it can hels someone else !